# change cursor when user click and hold click whithout javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I'm working on 'drag/drop' plugin grid that give users ability to move rows to reorder.

when a user put mouse over cell to move the row, I make following style to decorate mouse cursor:

```
td.reorder {cursor:grab;cursor:-moz-grab;cursor:-webkit-grab;}
```

Now. What I want:

- by clicking on row, I want the cursor to change
- changing the cursor by css, no javascript
- something like `td:click{cursor:grabbing}`
- if could: cursor still changed while user holding click

thanks

**Update**

I put an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mustint/f7k2muLc/7/) for my code.

please can you see if my events correct.

**Update 2**

This is [my Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/mustint/f7k2muLc/10/). It works fine.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without Javascript, the only "events" you can use in CSS are:

- `a:link` - a normal, unvisited link
- `a:visited` - a link the user has visited
- `a:hover` - a link when the user mouses over it
- `a:active` - a link the moment it is clicked .

(http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

I suggest you use:

```
jQuery('td').on("click", function() {
    jQuery(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
});
```

Comment: In my code I have to use jquery event.
but "jquery click event" set the cursor, I should write second event to get cursor back when mouse leave the click holding